# Why are chars only 8 bits in size?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, char, size

In most standard systems, a char is 8 bits in size.  Using Shannon's equation:

8 bits = log2N

N must equal 256.

However, on the Unicode table there are far more than 256 characters.  And on my compiler, when I run the following lines of code:

```
char c = static_cast<char> (257);

cout << c;
```

I see an unknown character printed to the screen, but a character nonetheless.

However, I've run some tests where I put many chars in a file, and the file's size corresponds with the char = 8 bit ratio.

So, it seems like a char is 8 bits (at least on my system), but I'm still seeing something printed to the screen at 257 and above, as well as there being many more chars than 256 on the unicode table.

Comment: A `char` is not a character (in the Unicode sense), but a "byte", i.e. the elementary addressable thing.

Comment: When C and C++ were initially designed in the 1970's they couldn't easily use Unicode, because that didn't exist.

Comment: If by "put many chars in a file", you mean bytes (octets), that makes sense of course. But if you mean text, then you have chosen a specific character encoding that likely encodes all of your sample text with one byte per character (or replaces unsupported characters with a character that it encodes with one byte). In C++, `char` does not imply text. For example,  your 257 does not seem to be intended as a text character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte by `C++` standard. Keep in mind that it does not indicate that the size will be 8 bits, since not on every system the statement `byte = 8 bits` is true. For the sake of explanation, assume that we're talking only about 8 bit bytes.

First of all, when you write:

> `8 bits = log2N` and thus `N must equal 256`

You are right. 8 bits can represent up to `256` different values, and the fact that Unicode consists of more characters than that has nothing to do with the problem. `char` is not meant to represent every possible character out there. It is meant to represent one of `256` different values that can be interpreted to *[some range of printable or non printable characters](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html)*.

> However, on the Unicode table there are far more than 256 characters. And on my compiler, when I run the following lines of code:
>
> ```
> char c = static_cast<char> (257);
> cout << c;
> ```
>
> I see an unknown character printed to the screen, but a character nonetheless.

But have you tried actually determinatig what does `static_cast<char>(257)` return?

```
char c = static_cast<char>(257);
std::cout << static_cast<int>(c);
```

Will print **`1`**, and as we dive into Unicode (or ASCII) table, we can see that this value represents the [Start of Heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) character. It is a non printable character and printing it will result in an undefined character appearing on the console (*need confirmation whether or not this is truly undefined*).

For printing a wider range of characters, consider using `wchar_t` (which is most likely to be `16` bits, thus it can cover a range of 65536 values) and `std::wstring` to correspond to it.

Answer (score 1):

Char is 8 bit for historical reasons. When C programming was developed most output was on dumb terminals. The dumb terminals displayed characters based on the ASCII character encoding. ASCII characters ranged between 0 - 255. This handled most printable characters for English.
Considering all languages, there are much more than 256 characters.  Additional character encoding were developed.  Unicode is one, UTF-8 is another.

Comment: ASCII ranges between 0 and 127. Unicode is a _character set;_ UTF-8 is a _character encoding_ for Unicode, as is UTF-16. UTF-16 is sometimes called Unicode because…UCS-2…26 years ago Unicode was a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory that a char would always be 8 bits in size. char is dependent on CHAR_BIT variable defined in limits.h. CHAR_BIT value is usually 8 on most systems, but the actual value depends on the particular system and library implementation. You can find more details on limit.h header file [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- If you run:

  ```
  char c = static_cast<char> (257);
  cout << static_cast<int> (c);
  ```

  In most probable case you will see `1`. The reason is indeed, char is 8-bit long and 257 is out of the range. In fact `char c` doesn't store 257 but 1.
- The way you store string doesn't have an affect on how you display it. It depends on your console character encoding.

Comment: Exactly: the issue is about **converting** between integral types.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of coding algorithm you are using. As for ascii, it is only from 0 to 255.

Comment: The range of ASCII character values is 0 to 127; the values from 128 to 255 are used by various Extended ASCII encodings. In particular, [ISO 8859](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) defines a dozen or so different encodings that use the top half of the range in different ways.